# Javascript date picker error in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have a page https://dev.leadformly.com/datepicker having an iframe
In that particular '', I am writing the HTML code dynamically by ajax call by the following code.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.post(URL,
        function (data) { //here it retruns the HTML code
          $("body").html('<iframe style="width:100%;height:384px;"></iframe>');
          $("body iframe")[0].contentDocument.write(data.democode);
        },
        'json'
      );
    });
</script>
```

Now when I click on the date picker it will throw an error in the console like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

Can you help me to resolve this issue? Or just explain the cause so it will help me to resolve it

Comment: Which datepicker are you using?

Comment: Default jquery datepicker - https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: The error seems to be encountered in `DateRangePicker`, which is not a jQuery datepicker. Can you double check?

Comment: It's Bootstrap "daterangepicker" and not jquery, sorry about that.

Comment: why you are using iframe anyway here? you are loading a different url, so what is the benefit of using iframe here?

Comment: There is an embed code which I need to use. So, am using iframe.

Comment: Have you access to javascript files of datepicker? If so, then try to use [solution](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1366#issuecomment-169437289) from GitHub.

Comment: Does datepicker work without the frame. Hit the iframe URL and check if its working independently. If yes, next step would be check it inside an iframe.

Comment: @dang can you share the code which  comes from ajax. (`data.democode`)

Comment: [Second paramter of `jQuery` `post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) is data to be posted, which is incorrect in your case. Also provide more code to understand what you trying to solve. JsFiddle or similar set up would help us.

Answer (score 12):

You're getting this error because you're trying to access the internal `DOM` of an `iFrame` from the parent `DOM` containing it. The "click" event from the parent `DOM` cannot make calls to the elements inside a child `iFrame`.

May I ask why you are trying to use an `iFrame` in this situation? I can almost assure you you are better off not using it.

Answer (score 3):

I think jQuery is not able to read the iframe element that is why it is showing 
**Cannot read property top of undefined** error.

Use `id="ifreame"` in iframe element then it should work.

```
<iframe id="ifreame" style="width:100%;height:384px;"></iframe>
```

jQuery

```
$("body #iframe")[0].contentDocument.write(data.democode);
```

Answer (score 3):

The final option you have is to try using the sandbox property.

`allow-scripts: Allows the embedded browsing context to run scripts (but not create pop-up windows). If this keyword is not used, this operation is not allowed.`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

If this does not work, please move away from iframe. iframe element is created to be a sandboxed environment and is prone to very high security risks when you open the allow-scripts. The resulting web page/external site put in iframe can do anything... literally anything from getting access to credentials, cookies, access, etc if you remove sandboxing.

Iframe is highly not recommended if you want to access DOM in its content. If full or partial isolation is your only concern please try using web component's isolation method to:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components